# If d is a metric on X and f is a non negative, continuos function, then d'=f(d(x,y)) is a topologically equivalent metric to d

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:[0,+\infty) \to [0,+\infty)$ a continuos function such that:

1. $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0\}$
2. $f(c)\leq f(a)+f(b),\quad \forall c\leq a+b$.

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space. Prove that the function $d':X\times X \to \mathbb{R}, \quad d'(x,y)=f(d(x,y))$ is a metric over $X$ and show that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent.

I managed to prove that $d'$ is a metric over $X$, however, I don't know how to show that it is topologically equivalent to $d$. My idea is to show that every open disk with respect to $d$ contains an open disk with respect to $d'$ and viceversa. I have found out that $f$ is strictly increasing if that helps. Anyone who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to show that convergent sequences in both metrics coincide.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use the hypothesis in terms of convergent sequences?

Comment: Well, $x_n\to a$ if and only if $d(x_n,a)\to 0$. So if $d(x_n,a)\to 0$ then by continuity of $f$ this implies $d'(x_n,a)\to 0$. On the other hand if $d'(x_n,a)\to 0$ then $f(d(x_n,a))\to 0$. Now you know that $f$ is strictly increasing and maps $0$ to $0$. Then the only option is that $d(x_n,a)\to 0$. And so convergent sequences have to coincide.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you very much!

Comment: If $a \le b$, then $a \le 0 + b$, so $f(a) \le f(0) + f(b) = f(b)$. Thus $f$ is necessarily increasing. If play around with ball sizes, you should find that "strictly" is not needed.